# CURSOR Table Error When Executing: Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, cursor

I am trying to pass two values in my function using CURSOR table. Is this correct? I modified this post from earlier. When I execute this function, it executes successfully. Just unsure how to test in SQL.

```
 USE [PMCLW1]
 GO
 /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[func_PNMS_CA]    Script Date: 08/13/2013 14:41:16 ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER function [dbo].[func_PNMS_CA](@SCRDET_Seqid int, @JobSeqid int) 
 returns varchar(5000)
 as
 begin
declare @retVal varchar(5000),
        @temp varchar(1000)

declare CACur CURSOR FOR

SELECT top 1 isnull (SPCOPS_Answer, '') FROM SPCOPS WHERE SCRDET_Seqid = @SCRDET_Seqid

declare CACur CURSOR FOR

SELECT b.JBSTAT_Description
          FROM JBWORK a
            inner join JBSTAT b on a.JBSTAT_SEQID = b.JBSTAT_SEQID
          WHERE  a.PRJOBS_SEQID = @JobSeqid
          and a.dptmnt_seqid=7

OPEN CACur

FETCH NEXT FROM CACur 
INTO @temp

set @retVal = ''

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF len(@retVal) = 0 set @retVal = @temp
    ELSE set @retVal = @retVal + ', ' + @temp

    FETCH NEXT FROM CACur 
    INTO @temp
END

close CACur
deallocate CACur

return @retVal
 end
```

Comment: You have `DECLARE CURSOR FOR`, then `(SELECT)`, then another `SELECT`. What is this second `SELECT` supposed to be doing? Right now it is trying to return that query before your cursor is even opened. A function can only return one value.

Comment: I was trying to pull in an id and description from a table based on a specific dptmnt_seqid.

Comment: Well you can't do that with two separate queries. Did you mean to write a join, or a subquery, or ...? Could you show a few rows of sample data and desired results? I'm fairly confident this can be done much more concisely.

Comment: I was trying to write a subquery.

Comment: If you show what it was actually supposed to do (as I asked), or maybe even start by giving the function a readable and meaningful name, we can help. I don't know how to fix "I was trying to write a subquery" because that could mean so many things.

Comment: I'm trying to pass two values from my function. I wish I could provide sample data, but, dont know how to.